# Division and subtraction with log probabilities

Tags: probability, logarithms

I implemented [log probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability) in Java to do some calculations with better accuracy (less compounding rounding errors). I managed to get addition and multiplication working, but I also need to do subtraction and division. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you be more explicit, by taking examples...

Comment: Let's say I have probabilities 0.8 and 0.2. I want to calculate `0.8 - 0.2` by using their log probabilities, which are -0.2231 and -1.6094 when using `e` as the base. How could I do this?

Comment: why do you want to do this?? you could do this with exp function. $e^{0.8-0.2}=e^{0.8}/e^{0.2}$